# How to get value from nested array?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I've below JSON structure, and I'd like to get the interface name if type is "DHCP".

```json
{
    "host": [
        {
            "interfaces": [
                {
                    "bootproto": "none", 
                    "name": "ens5f0", 
                    "nets": [
                        {
                            "ipaddr": "10.1.1.10", 
                            "type": "DHCP", 
                        },
                        {
                            "ipaddr": "10.1.1.10", 
                            "type": "STATIC", 
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "bootproto": "none", 
                    "name": "ens5f1", 
                    "nets": [
                        {
                            "ipaddr": "10.1.1.11", 
                            "type": "STATIC", 
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "bootproto": "none", 
                    "name": "ensf2", 
                    "nets": [
                        {
                            "ipaddr": "192.168.1.1", 
                            "type": "DHCP", 
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here the expected output is

```
['ens5f0', 'ens5f2']
```

I tried below Ansible play to get the install name.

```yaml
- name: Get DHCP interface name
  set_fact:
    dhcp_interfaces: "{{ main_host_network_interfaces[0].interfaces | map(attribute='nets') | flatten | selectattr('type', 'match', 'DHCP') | list }}"
```

but it returns the

```json
{
    "ipaddr": "10.1.1.10", 
    "type": "DHCP", 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the filter *json_query*

```yaml
  dhcp_interfaces: "{{ host|json_query(_query) }}"
  _query: '[].interfaces[?nets[?type == `DHCP`]].name|[]'
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  dhcp_interfaces:
    - ens5f0
    - ensf2
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    host:
      - interfaces:
        - bootproto: none
          name: ens5f0
          nets:
          - {ipaddr: 10.1.1.10, type: DHCP}
          - {ipaddr: 10.1.1.10, type: STATIC}
        - bootproto: none
          name: ens5f1
          nets:
          - {ipaddr: 10.1.1.11, type: STATIC}
        - bootproto: none
          name: ensf2
          nets:
          - {ipaddr: 192.168.1.1, type: DHCP}

    dhcp_interfaces: "{{ host|json_query(_query) }}"
    _query: '[].interfaces[?nets[?type == `DHCP`]].name|[]'

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: dhcp_interfaces
```

Comment: I trust you , seem to be complicated , for what he want no ?
If he takes several more machines, he won't add them manually in the playbook... 

Use fact with attributes ?

Or explain me im sure i didnt have your experience

Answer (score -1):

well !

try this :

```
set_fact:
  interfaces: "{{ host[0].interfaces | selectattr('nets.type', 'equalto', 'DHCP') | map(attribute='name') | list }}"
```

equalto was added in version 2.8 you can check if it is avalaible with pip list | grep Jinja2.
equalto is introduced in ver. 2.8.

Comment: nets.type will fail as 'nets' is a array

Comment: yep my bad indeed : "{{ host[0].interfaces | selectattr('nets', 'contains', {'type': 'DHCP'}) | map(attribute='name') | list }}" this one will sucess  
If its succeed ping me ! i will change my answer, otherwise im just a newbie